# R2WinBUGS - how to reload the WinBUGS computation results to bugs object again

Tags: r, winbugs, r2winbugs, winbugs14

I have run a looong computation in WinBUGS (million iterations) using the R2WinBUGS package from within R:

```
bugs.object <- bugs(...)
```

but the R crashed. **How do I reload the bugs.object into R again without running winbugs again?** I tried this (I have 3 chains):

```
out <- read.bugs(paste("coda", 1:3, ".txt", sep = ""))
```

but the `out` data structure is completely diferent from the bugs object (as it is, it is unusable). I tried to convert it with `as.bugs.array`:

```
bugs.object <- as.bugs.array(out, model.file = "ttest.txt", n.iter = 1000000, n.burnin = 300000, n.thin = 2, program = "WinBUGS")
```

but it doesn't work. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Cross posted: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15262/how-to-reload-the-winbugs-computation-results-to-bugs-object-again

Comment: start by looking at `str(out)`, `class(out)` (you could post the results, although `str(out)` might give voluminous output).  As specified by `?read.bugs`, you should get an object of class `mcmc.list` which can then be analyzed using `coda` functions ... ?

Answer (score 3):

It is likely that you are reading a error message, where R ran out of memory to create the `bugs.array` object.

You can get round this problem by setting the `codaPkg=T` statement in the `bugs` function. This saves the CODA files in your specified working directory rather than creating the R2WinBUGS object (before R crashes). Then you can read the coda files back in using `read.mcmc` in the coda package, and if you really want, convert the `mcmc` object to a `bugs.array`.

This might not work if your MCMC is too big or you do not have enough memory for R.